# and dare to fight, defy difficulties

Tags: word-usage

Is "and" in "and dare to fight, defy difficulties" used properly in English?

It appears to be a bit odd at the first glance, but then, it seems to be okay in some way. I am not sure.

> "People of the world, unite and defeat the aggressors and all their running dogs! People of the world, be courageous, **and dare to fight, defy difficulties** and advance wave upon wave. Then the whole world will belong to the people. Monsters of all kinds shall be destroyed."

> Source: YouTube

Comment: Yes, there is a list of things that people are being exhorted to do - be courageous _and_ dare... _and_ advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to analyze this:

> dare to [fight, defy difficulties and advance wave upon wave].

You "dare to" do three things:  fight, defy, and advance.

Comment: Cool. Thank you both.